# Macro input Value and extract rows accordingly

Tags: excel

This is an excel sheet with 4000 rows * 200 columns.

one column has 10 different names in the column.

Function of my macro is to first ask for the name of person whose report is required. Suppose I say "Ram" it will extract all the rows equal to that name and save the values in new workbook and save the file name as "Ram"

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would approach the macro:

```
' Prompt the user for a name '
Name = PromptForName

' Get your sheets (and create a new workbook) '
Set Src = ActiveSheet
Set Book2 = Workbooks.Add
Set Dst = Book2.Sheets(1)

' Copy headers from row 1 '
Src.Rows(1).Copy
Dst.Rows(1).PasteSpecial

' Assuming column A is your name column '
For Each cell In Src.Range("A2:A" & Src.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Cells
    If cell.Value = Name Then
        Src.Rows(cell.Row).Copy
        Dst.Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
    End If
Next

' Specify path to save (with name) '
Book2.SaveAs Name & ".xls"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this... does it make any sense?

```
    Sub valueMacro()

    Dim VariableSheetName As String

    Workbooks.Add

    VariableSheetName = InputBox("Sheet Name", "Enter sheet name", "")

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "T:\1AA\" & VariableSheetName 

    Dim strvalue As String
    strvalue = InputBox("Enter the name of FM")

    Dim wksDisc As Worksheet

    '' Set wksDisc = Sheets("T:\1AA\" & VariableSheetName)
     If Target.Column = E And Target.Value = strvalue Then
       Target.EntireRow.Copy
       wksDisc.Paste Destination:=wksDisc.Cells(Target.Row, 1)
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
     End If

    End Sub
```